# Fire an event handler after a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery

What I need is this:

If the user hover the element for more then 1 second, the event will happen, otherwise it should not.

I tried using the `setTimeout()` but it just delays the event and does not cancel it when the mouse leaves the element.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

```
$(".optionCont").live('mouseover', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".dropMenuCont").stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
        if($this.next().css("display") == "none"){
            $this.next().stop(true,true).slideDown(200);
        }else{
            $this.next().stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
        }
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;

    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could listen to  the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and clear the timer in the `mouseleave` event handler:

```
$(".optionCont").live('mouseenter', function(e){
     var $this = $(this);
     var timer = setTimeout(function(){
          //...
     }, 1000);
     $this.data('timer', timer);
}).live('mouseleave', function(e) {
     clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
});
```

**Update:**

Btw. these lines in the `setTimeout` callback

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

won't have any effect, as by the time the callback is executed, the event already bubbled up and triggered the default action (not to mention that `return false` from the callback does not mean anything). You have to put them directly into your event handler.

Comment: Why not `mouseover` and `mouseout`? Any difference? Anyhow, was going to answer with this [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/aqDhj/).

Comment: @Shadow: `mouseout` and `mouseover` will also be triggered if you enter a descendant of the element. And in most cases you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware to that. So the jQuery `.hover()` is actually using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Comment: @Shadow: Yes (it's in the documentation ;)). Also have a look at this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t28

Comment: I'm confused now.. does it mean jQuery has its own implementation of the IE only `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, making them cross browser?

Comment: @Shadow: I assume so. It is actually not that difficult, you just have to check whether the original target of the `mouseover` event is not the current element and then ignore it. `mouseleave` is more tricky. You have to check whether the node the mouse left to is a descendant or not (or something like that, maybe there are easier ways I'm not aware of).