# Jquery: Mouseover triggered after a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, html

i got the following problem: I got a h2, nested in a div with the id : `<div id="hidediv1">.` 
I got this code

```
$("#hidediv1").mouseover(function(){
  $('#hide1').show(500);
});
$("#hidediv1").mouseleave(function(){
  $('#hide1').hide(500);
});
```

I want it to be, that you have to hover over the div for atleast 1 second to trigger it.
I know, there are several questions on stackoverflow, but i coulnd't apply them to my code. 
Please help!
 Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire an event handler after a certain amount of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148447/fire-an-event-handler-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay jquery hover event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay it using:

```
$("#hidediv1").mouseenter(function() {
  $('#hide1').delay(1000).show(500);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('#hide1').stop(true).hide(500);
});
```

`stop(true)` would avoid some queue pending issue.

BTW, you have better in most cases to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.

Comment: @tatanga1888 Because it bubbles, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover

Comment: the stop(true) was reeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaally helpful thank you!

Comment: @Jishnu V S sorry i didnt know it was a thing =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#div2").hide(1000);
});
$("#div1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#div2").show(1000);
    });
});
```

Try this..